# PHP variable function optimization

Tags: php

I am working on a small MVC for a project, and I am using a single string to control what classes are instantiated, and what methods are called. Everything works fine just the way it is, but I now want to add the ability to call methods with over the current limit of three parameters. Of course, this is easy to do within the switch statement, but is there another way of doing it for a varying amount of arguments? In the future, I might want to call methods this way using ten parameters or more.

```
function __construct()
    {
    /**
     * Get the url parameters.
     */
    $url = (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'Index');
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($url); $i++) {
        $url[$i] = ucfirst(strtolower($url[$i]));
    }

    $file = 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    } else {
        error();
    }

    /**
     * @var $controller Controller
     */
    $controller = new $url[0];
    $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

    /*
     * Call additional methods on the controller if requested.
     */
    $args = max(sizeof($url) - 2, 0);
    if (sizeof($url) > 1) {
        switch ($args) {
            case 0:
                if (method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                    $controller->{$url[1]}();
                    $controller->index();
                } else {
                    error();
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (method_exists($controller, $url[1]))
                    $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
                else
                    error();
                break;
            case 2:
                if (method_exists($controller, $url[1]))
                    $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2], $url[3]);
                else
                    error();
                break;
            case 3:
                if (method_exists($controller, $url[1]))
                    $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2], $url[3], $url[4]);
                else
                    error();
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $controller->index();
    }
}
```

Is this optimization possible in PHP, or do I just have to hardcode the extra cases in the switch statement? Performance is not an issue. Simplicity and generalization are much more sought after.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `call_user_func_array` to do that

First you can pull out of the array the controller name and method name:

```
$controller = count($url) > 0 ? array_shift($url) : 'DefaultController'; //Pop off of the array first element or default controller
$method = count($url) > 0 ? array_shift($url) : 'Index'; //Second element or Default Method
```

You can then do either:

```
call_user_func_array(array($object,$method), $url);
```

Or if it is a static function:

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller,$method), $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) you can remove the first item from an array and return it, so you can do this:

```
$controllerName = array_shift($url);
$method = array_shift($url);

$controller = new $controllerName;
$controller->loadModel($controllerName);
```

Because those items are actually removed, the remaining items in `$url` are the parameters and you can call the method using [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) like this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), $url);
```

This function calls the [*callable*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) specified in the first parameter. In this case, it's a reference to a method, by specifying an array with the object (the controller) and the name of the method to call.

The array in the second parameter is split and passed as individual arguments to the method.

Comment: Unshift puts an element at the start of the list